# Convert and Sum Time Intervals from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray

I'm very new to Objective-C and need a little help.  I have an array of songs:

```
   {
    artist = "Bernard Herrmann";
    duration = "2:34";
    id = 5;
    title = "Torn Curtain: The Unused Score";
},
    {
    artist = "Miklos Razsa";
    duration = "3:47";
    id = 6;
    title = "Ivanhoe [Original]";
},
...etc.
```

And I'd like to iterate through the array, converting the durations(currently `NSStrings`) to something I can use to represent the actual elapsed time, then add them up so that I can get a count of total time to play the playlist. I've started working on the loop:

**UPDATED:**

```
- (NSInteger)convertDuration
{
    NSInteger totalSeconds=0;
    for(NSMutableArray *song in playlist){
        NSString *durationString = [playlist valueForKey:@"duration"];
        NSArray *breakMinSec = [durationString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSInteger sec = [breakMinSec[1]integerValue];
        NSInteger min = [breakMinSec[0]integerValue];
        totalSeconds += ( sec + min * 60 );
        }
    return totalSeconds;
}
```

It looks like as of right now, durationString is pulling all of the durations in the first iteration.  It won't compile like this.  How can I be sure only to get a single duration for each iteration?

Comment: Try something before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cocoa touch quick way to sum a property in all objects within an NSSet](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1107299), [Sum duplicate on NSMutableArray](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13124857), [Sum an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4643766)

Comment: I'm having a little trouble applying any of the answers to those questions to my specific problem.  If someone could help connect the dots for me, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Parse the "minutes.seconds" into it's two pieces and convert to integer seconds.  Then add.  Study the NSString doc for several options to do the parsing, probably `componentsSeparatedByString`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here no need to convert it into NSTimeInterval or NSDate. You can simply add all durations to an array. Then break minutes and seconds, add all minutes and all seconds.

Then

```
 totalSeconds%=60;
 totalMinutes+=totalSeconds/60;
```

---

Edit: An idea how you can do (not compiler checked)

```
//NSMutableArray *durationArray=[NSMutableArray new];
NSInteger totalseconds=0;
for(NSDictionary *song in songDict){
    NSString *durationString=song[@"duration"];
    NSArray *breakMinSec=[durationString componentsSepartedByString:@":"];
    NSInteger sec=[breakMinsec[1]integerValue];
    NSInteger min=[[breakMinSec[0]integerValue];
    //[durationArray addObject:@[sec+min*60]];
    totalseconds+=(sec+min*60);
}
```

This will store each songs time in seconds. then you can manupulate this value as per your need.

EDIT:

After seeing your edit:

> How can I be sure only to get a single duration for each iteration?

You can send a value to your method that will return the duration for that specific song. Or as in my earlier answer, each duration was saved in index based array, you could have easily retrieved from there.

Comment: How are you converting the strings into numerical values that can be added?

Comment: @JoshCaswell : I am not 100% correct, but can we do as above, your guidance please?

Comment: `breakMinSec` is an array of `NSString`s, so you can't just stick the elements into `NSInteger`s; you need to get the `integerValue` of each, or some equivalent, before you can use `+` and `*` on them.

Comment: ohh yaa... as i just typed here only, so i missed that :p

Comment: This seems awfully complex... Do I really need an array for the durations?  Can't I just convert the individual `NSString`s and add them up separately?

Comment: Yeah, the guy only wanted the total time. No need for the array.  Just compute `int durationSeconds = [breakMinsec[1]integerValue] + ([breakMinsec[0]integerValue] * 60);  totalSeconds += durationSeconds; ... /* outside the loop */ totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;  totalSeconds = totalSeconds % 60;  NSString* outputTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:%02d", totalMinutes, totalSeconds);`

Comment: @RyanClark : You are right, he can do, but what about elapsed time for each songs? he cant subtract total-current to get elapsed time for an individual song, so I created array so that, individual and total time can be used separately.

Comment: I only need to have the total time as a result.  Individual times will only ever be displayed as a string.  So it's ok to only have them as numbers within this loop.

Comment: So you can remove the storage in the array ans simple go on to add each of them... you work is now a bit easier :)

Comment: @AKV I used some of your code with some changes and I've updated the question to reflect where I am with the problem. Thanks for all the help.